# Set Grass Region in Python grass.script

Tags: python, grass-gis, region, extend, grass.script

How can I set the Grass Region in Python without already having a map in the Mapset?
Basically I am looking for the equivalent to this window

[image]

Currently I am only able to extent an existing region, which leads in my case to very big regions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
import grass.script as grass

grass.run_command('g.region', n=10, s=9, e=35, w=33, ewres=0.1, nsres=0.2, verbose=True, flags='p')
    projection: 3 (Latitude-Longitude)
    zone:       0
    datum:      wgs84
    ellipsoid:  wgs84
    north:      10N
    south:      9N
    west:       33E
    east:       35E
    nsres:      0:12
    ewres:      0:06
    rows:       5
    cols:       20
    cells:      100
```

Comment: `g.region` requires in my Grass (6.4.3) a parameter <map> (Raster map to change). What version are you on? What am I doing wrong? In the [documentation](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/g.region.html) I don't see this parameter either.

Comment: No, g.region works on the overall "computational region", and is not specific to one map. That's the same for all version. THere is a different command, r.region which changes the extent and resolution of a single raster. Is that what you meant?